# Django Tastypie Nested parent / child

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a parent / child relationship in the same model. 
Example:

- Parent Comment
- - Child comment 01
  - - Child comment 02

I'd like to build an API that brings all of the child threads in nested fasion.
Currently it just brings up the parent comments.

My current API.py looks like this:

```
class ThreadResource(ModelResource):
    locations = fields.ToManyField('forum.api.comments','parent', full=True)

class Meta:
    queryset = comments.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'Comments'

class comments(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = comments.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'comms'
```

The way i did that in models is:

```
class comments(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True,null=True)
    sort = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to define a filter function that will return a queryset of the parent 
comments. Let's call it filter_comments_per_bundle:

```
def filter_comments_per_bundle(bundle);
    parent = bundle.obj
    return comments.objects.filter(parent=parent)
```

Next, just add a reference to self in the comments model resource:

```
children = fileds.ToManyField('self', filter_comments_per_bundle, full = True, null = True)
```

Lastly, sorry but it's a pet peeve. s/comments/Comment/ Models should be singular, with first letter capital.

Oh, and another thing. Don't name Models and ModelResources same. Rename comments ModelResource.